# How does program finds symbols in dynamic library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

Let's say I have 3 files `main.c`, `mylib.h` and `mylib.c`.

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", foo());
}
```

mylib.h:

```c
#pragma once

int foo();
```

mylib.c:

```c
#include "mylib.h"

int foo() { return 5; }
```

If I build `mylib` as dynamic library and link it to `main`, `main` will have dynamic reference to it:

```bash
>>> ldd main                                                                                                                
...
libmylib.so => /some_path/libmylib.so
...
```

I found out if I change `mylib.c`, rebuild `mylib` and `foo` symbol address will change, I don't need to rebuild / link again my `main` program.

Does symbol lookup happen in runtime as if I loaded library using `dlopen` and no external symbol addresses are stored in `main` program?

Comment: `Does symbol lookup happens in runtime as if I loaded library using dlopen and no external symbol addresses are stored in main program?` yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does symbol lookup happen in runtime as if I loaded library using `dlopen` and no external symbol addresses are stored in `main` program?

Yes.

Comment: Is it the same behavior on Windows?

Comment: @elo: Same principles, different details.